# script for only copy cells with value and ignore empty cells

Tags: javascript

i got this script. i want it to copy every cell with value in the active range and paste it somewhere else but i want it to ignore empty cells. as it is now it copys everyting, even the empty cells and copy/paste it to the new cell and erases the existing value.

```
function testreturn() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  if ( isInRange(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(),"BridgeuttagZEE") ) { //permisson
    var valuetocopy = spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getValues();
    if (valuetocopy === "") { return; }; //If cell value is empty stop code here
    
    spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(0, -13).activate();
    spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(0, 13).copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
    spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(0, 13).activate();
    spreadsheet.getActiveRange().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    spreadsheet.getActiveRange().clearNote();
  };
};
```

Comment: Start by verifying what `valuetocopy` actually contains, log it to console and check.

Comment: value1,,,value2 is what i am getting in the console log when i am testing it. i took a group of 4. first and last had value in it

Comment: Are those supposed to be five separate console.log results now, or is this the result of a single one (because the `valuetocopy` is actually an array)?

Comment: no its all in the same console.log result. i just marked one array of 4 cells in my google sheet and activated the function

Comment: So `valuetocopy` appears to be an array then(?, or comma-separated values in a string) - so comparing _that_ for equality with the empty string, makes little sense. And it also doesn't look to me as if your code was even setting the values cell-by-cell - but rather as if you are just specifying the starting position? Then the whole thing can hardly work the way you want to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

`getValues()` returns a 2D array in Google Apps Script, so equating it to `""` will never be `true`. You'll need to drill down into a reference such as `valuetocopy[i][j]` to get to the actual cell value.

It's not clear if your `getActiveRange()` call is supposed to return single row/column or multiple, so I'll assume that it's supposed to return a range that spans multiple rows and columns.

Also, if you have not enabled V8 runtime in your script, you can't write ES6 code. I'll give my example in ES5, and you can always convert it to ES6 if you want.

Your array from a selected range might look something like: `[[ValueA1, ValueA2, ], [ValueB1, , ], [ValueC1, ValueC2, ValueC3], [, , ], [, , ]]`.
You might purge the array like so:

```
var purged = valuetocopy.filter(function (currentRow) {
    const purgedRow = currentRow.filter(function(cell) {
      return cell !== ''; // Identify empty cells
    });
    if (purgedRow.length > 0) {
      return purgedRow; // only the rows with data in atleast one cell
    }
  });
  Logger.log(purged);
}
```

At this point, you have the non-empty rows in the same compatible 2D array format, so you could just go ahead and "paste" the array into any other range you'd like, using `setValues()`.